Functional derivative of the Shannon Mutual Information
I have a doubt concerning the calculation of the functional devivative of the Shannon mutual information. I have performed the calculation in two different ways and have two different
results. The question I have is where did I go wrong. The mutual information is defined in the following way:
\begin{equation}
I(X,Y)=\iint f(x,y) \log \frac{f(x,y)}{f(x) f(y)} dx dy
\end{equation}
reason why by introducing entropy I can write
\begin{equation}
I(X,Y)=H(x)+H(Y)-H(X,Y)
\end{equation}
I want to calculate the functional derivative of $I(X,Y)$ with respect to the probability density function $f(x)$. I can write:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta I(X,Y)}{\delta f(x)}=\frac{\delta H(x)}{\delta f(x)}+\frac{\delta H(Y)}{\delta f(x)}-\frac{\delta H(X,Y)}{\delta f(x)}=\frac{\delta H(x)}{\delta f(x)}=-1-\log f(x)
\end{equation}
I now consider the alternative solution, obtained by proceeding in a different way.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta I(X,Y)}{\delta f(x)}= \frac{\delta}{\delta f(x)} \left( \iint f(x,y) \log \frac{f(x,y)}{f(x) f(y)} dx dy \right)
\end{equation}
Using the properties of logarithms, I can write
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta I(X,Y)}{\delta f(x)}= -\frac{\delta}{\delta f(x)} \left( \iint f(x,y) \log f(x) dx dy \right)
\end{equation}
To calculate the functional derivative I can first calculate the perturbation of $f(x)$, then perform the derivative with respect to $\epsilon$ and finally I set $\epsilon = 0$.
The perturbation is:
\begin{equation}
\iint f(x,y) \log (f(x)+\epsilon \eta(x)) dx dy
\end{equation}
When differentiation with respect to $\epsilon$ I have:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{d \epsilon} \iint f(x,y) \log (f(x)+\epsilon \eta(x)) dx dy  = \int f(x,y) \frac{\eta(x)}{f(x) + \epsilon \eta(x))} dx dy
\end{equation}
And finally, setting  $\epsilon = 0$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{d \epsilon} \iint f(x,y) \log (f(x)+\epsilon \eta(x)) dx dy = \int f(x) \frac{\eta(x)}{f(x)} dx dy
\end{equation}
So that I conclude that $\frac{\delta I(X,Y)}{\delta f(x)}=1$.
I think this second solution is wrong for the reason that it does not take into account the fact that the integral of joint probabilities in $dy$ is equal to the margin PDF f(x).
Put another way, when I perturb $f(x)$, $f(x,y)$ should also be perturbed. Is this reasoning correct?
